# Connect to a MySQL database using access info on mysql db

Tags: mysql

I have a request from a customer and I am quite sure the answer is no, but wondering if someone has a different answer.

**Background**

As you know MySQL installation create a database called "mysql" where it stores the databases we create and also the users.

In the user table, there is a field called "authentication_string" where the user password is saved.

**Project**

On this project each time a customer creates an account a new database user and database is created.

When a customer logs in through a web interface, the system calls an API to authenticate him/her. After that the root db user is used to connect to customer database, not their own database credentials, why? because they do not want to save user and password on database (this is a temp solution)

They want to change the application so after authentication/authorization process and they would somehow only needed root credentials to somehow get user and password from "mysql db" and then use them to create the connection using customer db credentials.

Is this possible? Or is there some mysql parent - children configuration where this scenario is possible?

Project uses MySQL 5.7

Comment: `because they do not want to save user and password on database` but at the same time the see no problem acting as root for everyone? Nice logic :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that is a temp solution the idea is to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand I think you could just use MySQL’s [`SET PASSWORD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) to set some random strong password for the user and then login using that. This way you would not store anything and it would still be pretty secure assuming your root db access is fairly isolated from the thing that’s trying to login as the user.

For example:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR some_user = <long-strong-randomly-generated-password-string>
```

Afterwards you return this `<long-strong-randomly-generated-password-string>` from your access-providing process and then the user process can login using that. In this case it would stay valid until the next `SET PASSWORD`, so keep that in mind, but depending on your use-case that might be ok.